# How to make a jQuery function work for same element in all rows of a foreach loop instead of just the first row?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.net C# and I have a table for products where I have a function that gets called whenever there is a change in a dropdown list selection.

My function works perfect currently, but only if there is 1 row of data. If there is 2 or 3 rows or more, it only works for the top row and not individually for each row.

Based on a dropdown list selection my function gets the value from the dropdown list and sets that value to an empty hidden input text field. On the first row, the function works great when making a selection. If I go to the second row and so on, and make a selection, it only works for the first row.

I need to have this work individually for each row for the same dropdown list element when a selection is made and not only work for that row, but not affect the values that were already set from the previous row(s).

```html
<script>
  function selectedText(ddlitem) {
    selvalue = ddlitem.value;
    $('#Units').val(selvalue);
  }
</script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Units</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Products) {
    <tr>
      <td class="code">
        @item.Product_Code
      </td>
      <td class="descrip">
        @item.Description
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control qty-ctl" id="ncQty" name="ncQty" />
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Unit_Of_Measure, Extensions.GetUOMList(), "--Select Units--", new { id = "txt1", @class = "form-control uom-ctl", @onChange = "selectedText(this)" })
        <input type="hidden" id="Units" name="Units" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Any help figuring this out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Traverse the DOM to find the `input` related to the `select` which raised the event, and use `class` attributes on all repeated content as `id` must be unique. **However** I'd argue that what you're doing is absolutely pointless. Why set the value of a hidden field to match that of the visible field, when you can just use the visible field's value in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering arises from using the IDs for your list and hidden input field, in HTML. Each ID in HTML is meant to be unique on a page. If you have rows with elements sharing the ID your JavaScript will always refer to the first occurrence of that ID causing it to work only for the initial row.

To resolve this issue ensure that each row has IDs or consider using classes to manage events effectively. Here's how you can adjust your code;

1. **Utilize Classes of IDs**; Substituting IDs with classes, for your
   lists and hidden input fields will enable your JavaScript to target
   the elements of a row.
2. **Update the JavaScript Function**; Revise the function to locate the
   hidden input field associated with the chosen dropdown option.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Units</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Products) {
    <tr>
      <td class="code">
        @item.Product_Code
      </td>
      <td class="descrip">
        @item.Description
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control qty-ctl" name="ncQty" />
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Unit_Of_Measure, Extensions.GetUOMList(), "--Select Units--", new { @class = "form-control uom-ctl ddl", @onChange = "selectedText(this)" })
        <input type="hidden" class="hidden-units" name="Units" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

JS:

```
function selectedText(ddlitem) {
  var selvalue = ddlitem.value;
  $(ddlitem).closest('tr').find('.hidden-units').val(selvalue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @YUSOF KHAN!!! That fixed it and is working perfectly! I can't thank you enough. I was stuck on that problem for a couple days now and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I also appreciate your detailed explanation of your answer too. It was very helpful!

Comment: @Kip M. I am glad, I was able to help. You're very welcome and good luck!!